# Python - Add rows based on information in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add rows in Python based on the information in some of the columns. For example let's say this is my data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,3],
    'E Test':['Y','Y','N'],
    'M Test':['Y','Y','Y'],
})
```

[image]

For the row with ID equal to 1, I'd like to add a column that says if the column labeled "E Test" equals "Y" then new column "Test Date" equals "April 1". I'd like to do the same for the "M Test" but with a different date and add a completely new row for the ID equal to 1. Therefore there would be 2 rows that have the ID equal to 1 and with different "Test Date" numbers.

Here is what it would look like ideally:

[image: Ideal]

Comment: hi and welcome! Thank you for providing an example of your input data. I've edited your question so that it's easier for people to create a pandas dataframe from your input. Can you please add a screenshot of what you expect your output to be?

Comment: if you are happy with one of the answers below please accept it with the green checkmark button

Answer (score 1):

I use two different dates to show how they can be individually changed.

```
df2 = df.melt('ID', var_name='Test', value_name='Test Date')
df2['Test'] = df2['Test'].str[0]
df2.replace({'Y': True, 'N': np.nan}, inplace=True)
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
df2.loc[df2['Test'].eq('E'), 'Test Date'] = '1-Apr'
df2.loc[df2['Test'].eq('M'), 'Test Date'] = '2-Apr'
df2 = df2.sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   ID Test Test Date
0   1    E     1-Apr
1   1    M     2-Apr
2   2    E     1-Apr
3   2    M     2-Apr
4   3    M     2-Apr
```

Filtered down to just `ID == 1`:

```
print(df2[df2['ID'].eq(1)])

...

   ID Test Test Date
0   1    E     1-Apr
1   1    M     2-Apr
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question on this, if my data set were bigger could I scale this?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'bigger'.

Comment: A dataframe with 2600 original rows

Comment: Okay, that tells me nothing more about the problem. Are you going to have tons of different Tests/Date combinations? Will there be more than just `Y` and `N`? Do you want to keep rows with `N`?

Comment: No more Tests/Date combinations. There will only by Y and N. Do not want to keep rows with N.

Comment: Well then yes, there's absolutely no reason why you couldn't just run my current code on a larger dataframe...

Answer (score 0):

Generated test data :

```
   ID E TEST M TEST
0   1      Y      Y
1   3      Y      N
2   4      Y      N
3   5      N      Y
4   6      N      Y
5   7      Y      N
6   8      Y      Y
7   9      Y      Y
8  10      N      Y
```

Then:

```
test_dates={'E':'1-Apr','M':'1-May'}

df = df.melt(id_vars='ID').sort_values(['ID','variable']) \
    .assign(Test=lambda x: x['variable'].str.slice(0,1)) \
    .assign(**{'Test Date': lambda x: x['Test'].map(test_dates)}) \
    .loc[lambda x: x['value']=='Y',['ID','Test','Test Date']].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Which results in:

```
    ID Test Test Date
0    1    E     1-Apr
1    1    M     1-May
2    3    E     1-Apr
3    4    E     1-Apr
4    5    M     1-May
5    6    M     1-May
6    7    E     1-Apr
7    8    E     1-Apr
8    8    M     1-May
9    9    E     1-Apr
10   9    M     1-May
11  10    M     1-May
```